# How can I get and display ForeignKey data in a Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm attempting to only display cards based on their `category_name`.

for eg. I have 2 simple models, Product and Category:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=False, null=False)
    url_name = models.SlugField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    category_image = models.ImageField(
        null=False, blank=False, default='', upload_to='category_images', help_text='This will be the category image')
    category_description = RichTextField(default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

    def get_category_name(self):
        return self.category_name


class Product(models.Model):
    main_product_image = models.ImageField(
        null=False, blank=False, default='', upload_to='product_images', help_text='This will be the main image in the carousel.')
    alternative_image_1 = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True, upload_to='product_images', help_text='This will be the first image in the carousel.')
    alternative_image_2 = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True, upload_to='product_images', help_text='This will be the second image in the carousel.')
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category', null=True, blank=True, help_text='Assign product to category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_creator', null=True)

    sku = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    product_display_description = RichTextField(default='')
    spice_rating = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    has_sizes = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='0')
    add_to_carousel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I would like to then display these product cards on the frontend based on their category names.

Using something simple like this:

```
{% for product in products_processor|slice:':4' %}
{% if product.category.category_name == 'sauces' %}
<div class="item"></div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def all_products(request):
    """Shows and displays all products."""
    products = Product.objects.all()
    query = None
    categories = None
    sort = None
    direction = None

    if request.GET:

        # Handles sorting by price, rating etc...
        if 'sort' in request.GET:
            sortkey = request.GET['sort']
            sort = sortkey
            if sortkey == 'name':
                sortkey = 'lower_name'
                products = products.annotate(lower_name=Lower('name'))
            if sortkey == 'category':
                sortkey = 'category__name'
            if 'direction' in request.GET:
                direction = request.GET['direction']
                if direction == 'desc':
                    sortkey = f'-{sortkey}'
            products = products.order_by(sortkey)

        # Handles categories
        if 'category' in request.GET:
            categories = request.GET['category'].split(',')
            products = products.filter(category__url_name__in=categories)
            categories = Category.objects.filter(url_name__in=categories)

        # Handles Searches
        if 'q' in request.GET:
            query = request.GET['q']
            if not query:
                messages.error(request, 'Please enter a search query!')
                return redirect(reverse('products'))

            queries = Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(
                product_display_description__icontains=query)
            products = products.filter(queries)

    current_sorting = f'{sort}_{direction}'

    product_context = {
        'products': products,
        'search_term': query,
        'current_categories': categories,
        'current_sorting': current_sorting,
    }

    return render(request, 'products/products.html', product_context)


def product_detail(request, product_id):
    """Displays individual products."""
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)

    product_context = {
        'product': product,
    }

    return render(request, 'products/product_detail.html', product_context)
```

This method doesn't seem to be working. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of errors? It seems like it should be correct, but if you template is typed out exactly as what you posted  you are just putting some empty div tags onto the page.

Comment: Hi Nathan, there is a product card in the div tags i just cut it down for space purposes. I thought this should work too but unfortunately, it's not displaying anything. And no, no errors.

Comment: Can you also show your view that is creating this page?

Comment: Sure, i've edited the question with the views.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I see in your view. In your template you are doing `{% for product in products_processor|slice:':4' %}`, in which `products_processor` seems like it is supposed to be part of your context. The issue I see is that your context object from your view does not contain a `products_processor`, only a `products`. Maybe try replacing `products_processor` with `products` in your template.

Comment: Apologies for the long response but that's it! Thanks for the help Nathan.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.